# why negative voted questions are hidden from featured list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, down-votes

It's something special with negative numbers? 
there is something like an absolute zero for votes?

I can't understand why zero is so important.

I would like my question be seen in the list, I have totally reworded it, but there is no easy way someone could note that because is hidden..

To delete and create a new question perhaps is what one should do in this case

(but paradox, I can't delete a bounty question)

Comment: Hopefully it makes sense that we want to have good questions featured... anyway, is there some reason you added the [tag:feature-request] tag? What feature are you requesting?

Comment: I thought was pretty clear: **Stop hiding negative voted questions**, math behind this is : p people upvote, and n>p people downvote, n=p+diff then if you calculate the percentage of people voted up is 

P=100 * p/(p+n) = 100 * p / (p + p +diff)

if p=100, diff=5, then 48% of people likes the question, and this without having account the potential people that don't even read the question because the hide! or biased by the differencial vote count shown

Comment: in that analysis you would have to make the case that the question which 48% of people liked is more deserving of attention than some other question which _more than_ 50% (typically: 80-90%) of people liked enough to upvote. I'm not convinced.

Answer (score 3):

First: You question appears in my browser:

[image]

Are you running a UserScript of some kind?

---

Second, [your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5241/520) is a mess.

It's not stupid, nor necessarily wrong, but it conflates at least two problems and is riddled with imprecise statements.

Things I find troubling about the question (i.e. things you could try fixing):

- You seem to have framed a question about the ["measurement problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem) in terms of the double slit experiment. That's unnecessary complication and can only distract from the issue at hand (and to tell the truth, I'm not sure which issue you really want addressed).
- Making a analogy to alpha--atom scattering in an attempt to understand photon--bulk-material interaction is deeply silly: they simply don't share enough physics for this to make sense. (The target in the Rutherford experiment was carefully prepared to have a thickness on order of a small integer number of atoms because alphas have very short ranges in matter.)

Comment: If you want to talk about the question, you can comment the question, this is meta, and here I didn't say nothing about Rutherford, I am talking on not to hide a question, if you don't like slit experiment question you can downvote that, but why would I put a bounty knowing it will be hidden? it has no sense! that's what my meta question is about

Comment: @HDE: Applying a bounty to a low voted question looks like an attempt to bring extra attention to content the community *does not think is any good* (that what down votes mean). Attention is one of the *rewards* in the Stack Exchange system, and we do not what to reward or endorse poor content. I tried to explain why you question is being judged harshly. You can do with that as you will.

Comment: I did a complete reword of the question, just because is same intention I keep the title, I should make a new one